# RISC-V: S-format instructions table

Tags: riscv, instruction-set

[image]

I have this table of S-format instructions. Can you explain to me what `imm[11:5]` and `funct3` are? I know `funct` indicates its size in bits and sometimes it is 000 or 010. I don't know exactly why it's there. Also, `imm[11:5]` is also 7-bits of all 0s.

Please help!

Comment: Please indicate what you have researched already.  Also, it would be best to have the table in the question itself as opposed to linking an image.

Comment: Please consult section 2.2 in riscv-spec-v2.2pdf, and also Chapter 19 in same.

Answer (score 0):

`imm[4:0]` and `imm[11:5]` denote closed-intervals into the bit-representation of the immediate operand.

The S-format is used to encode store instructions, i.e.:

```
sX rs2, offset(r1)
```

There are different types of store instructions, e.g. *store-byte* (`sb`), *store-half-word* (`sh`), *store-word* (`sw`), etc. The `funct3` part is used to encode the type (i.e. `0b00` -> `sb`, `0b010` -> `sw`, `0b011` -> `sd`, etc.). This allows to just use one (major) opcode while still having multiple types of store instructions - instead of having to waste several (major) opcodes. IOW, `funct3` encodes the minor opcode of the instruction.

The immediate operand encodes the offset. If you ask yourself why it's split like this - it allows to increase similarity of the remaining parts in the encoding with other instruction formats. For example, the opcode, rs1, and funct3 parts are located at the exact same place in the R-type, I-type and B-type instruction formats. The rs2 part placement is shared with the R-type and B-type instruction formats. Those similarities help to simplify the instruction decoder.

That means the offset is 12 bit wide and in pseudo-code:

```
offset = sign_ext(imm[11:5] << 5 | imm[4:0])
```

See also the first figure in Section 2.6 (Load and Store Instruction) of the [RISC-V Base specification](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual) (2019-06-08 ratified):

[image: RISC-V S-type instruction format]